# How to turn off sounds for everything except alarm

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

To make sure my alarm will wake me up, I turn the ringer volume up to max and turn my iPhone off of silent.

This results in keyboard clicks, notifications, screenshots etc. being unbearably loud. I would prefer them to always be silent.

How can I make everything on my iPhone silent except for:

- music/video I choose to play, play this at my specified volume
- alarm, play this at max volume

Comment: at least for the alarm (i. e.: while you are sleeping), one entirely half-assed solution might be to turn on flight mode. No network means (almost) no notifications. Starting with whatever the current iOS beta version is, there is also "focus" mode that blocks most notifications, with some heuristics and options to choose what to let through,

Comment: Alarms work even on silent mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered by [@Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

> Alarms work even on silent mode.

My iPhone has been on silent mode ever-since I had it. You can manage the alarm sound level for the alarm you create while selecting the alarm sound. Tap Edit on the alarm entry --> tap Sound --> Choose the sound and immediately increase the volume using volume buttons.

Just keep the Silent Mode on by sliding down the physical Silent Mode switch. Your music will play at the volume level you want. No screenshot/camera/notification sounds will ever come out. Don't Disturb would be a different outcome.

Comment: Camera sounds are territory-dependent, btw. In some jurisdictions it's illegal to disable the camera click.

Comment: @Tetsujin yup I only recently realized that and for example: Japan.